# mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'db' (2)

Tags: python, mysql, django, azure, docker

- I've dockerized my django web app.
- Whenever i run "docker-compose up" everything works fine and it opens
  locally
- But when i run "python manage.py runserver" it pops up an error
  **mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'db' (2)**
- This is the same error it is showing when i deployed it to azure
- When docker-compose up runs without error locally and the web app works well

here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
services:
db:
  image: mysql
  ports:
    - '3306:3306'
  environment:
     MYSQL_DATABASE: 'app'
     MYSQL_USER: 'root'
     MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'aspilos'
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'aspilos'
web:
  build: .
  command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  volumes:
    - .:/aspilos
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  depends_on:
    - db
```

Here is my utils.py file

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="db",
  user="root",
  passwd="aspilos",
  database="aspilos_log",
  auth_plugin="mysql_native_password"
) 
 mycursor = mydb.cursor()
 mycursor.execute("SELECT CONCAT('+', PHONE_NUMBER) FROM category2")
 results = mycursor.fetchall()
 for i in zip(*results):
 number = list(i)
 number1 = '+2348076548894'
 print (number)
```

Here is my settings.py file

```
DATABASES = {
 'default': {
   'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
   'NAME': 'app',
   'USER': 'root',
   'PASSWORD': 'aspilos',
   'HOST': 'db',
   'PORT': '3306',
  },
}
```

Comment: Check the docker-compose output for the container name of the database and use that as the hostname.

Comment: It didn't work. The container name for the database is aspilos_db_1. I tried it now it's bringing another error mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'aspilos_db_1' (0)

Comment: Then try to set a hostname explicitly in Yaml and check the DNS resolution in the containers.

Comment: how do  i do that please?

Comment: this is your host > `'HOST': 'db',` Since the hostname is `aspilos_db_1`, you have to change this `db` for `aspilos_db_1`, a note here, always remember that Docker names this with foldername_servicename_servicenumber,

Comment: @abestrad. i"ve done that. I'm gettting the same error, mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'db' (0)

Comment: Did you change your **settings.py** and  **utils.py** ?

Comment: I changed everything to aspilos_db_1

Comment: mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'aspilos_db_1' (0)

Comment: One factor here is, that Compose will not wait for the db to get up, and web might be requesting data before the db is ready. To discard this, try to get up running first the db, `docker-compose up -d db`, and `docker-compose ps` after check the `db` is up, `docker-compose up -d web`

Comment: Both of them are up and running.

Comment: When i run docker-compose build and docker compose up. It starts the db and web locally without errors but python manage.py runserver is the one throwing the error

Answer (score 0):

> "docker-compose up" everything works fine and it opens locally But when i run `"python manage.py runserver"` it pops up an error
> `mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'db' (2)`

Database Host `DB` will only work in the [docker-compose network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/). You can connect to other service using service name inside docker-compose but it becomes invalid outside of the docker-network.

A common error that can occur in docker-compose is when Database is not yet ready but application try to connect, a quick and dirty fix for that can be

```
 webapp:
   build: .
   image: webapp
   command: sh -c "sleep 30s ; python /app/manage.py"
```

But you should implement retry logic.

To deal with the above error you need a DNS that host or system can resovle

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="REACHABLE_IP",
....
)
```

You can verify reachable IP by connecting through the DB, it can

```
MySQL -h REACHABLE_IP -u db_user -pPass
```

Comment: how do i know the reachable ip please

Comment: How you run the script? you check system IP to make it working, localhost does not work.

Comment: my system's ip address is 192.168.0.1 but it isn't working either

Comment: when you deployed it to azure, did you run `docker-compose up`?

Comment: can you verify db connection from mysql client? is database running? `you should run`docker-compose up`?

Comment: docker compose up is running. The problem is that python manage.py is not running

Comment: python manage.py runserver is flagging the error, that is where the problem is and that is the same error i'm getting on azure

Comment: Python manage.py runserver is bringing the error "mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'db' (0)". This is the same error i get on azure. But When i run docker-compose up everything works fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217214/discussion-between-adiii-and-dmd).

Comment: what was the resolution of this? Did you fix it? How? I am facing a similar problem